# Doesn't every undirected graph have a cycle (eg, $a$-$b$-$a$ for nodes $a$ and $b$ joined by an edge)?

Tags: graph-theory

**Why there is no circular path in every undirected-graph?**

**For example:** Given 2 nodes a & b and one undirected edge that connects them

There is a cycle graph a-b-a

Plus,What's the **exact** definition of circular path?

Comment: Another example if I have only the node a then I could take: a-a

Comment: Cycles don't repeat edges, so $a$-$b$-$a$ is not cycle if only one edge joins $a$ and $b$. For reference, consider Wikipedia's  ["cycle (graph theory)" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)), which defines a cycle as a kind of "trail", where a ["trail"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#Walk,_trail,_path) requires distinct edges. ... Anyway, you've posted a few exercises from graph theory recently. Doesn't your textbook define such terms for you? (BTW: the `graphing-functions` tag isn't relevant to such questions. You can stop adding it. :)

Comment: As to your commented example of $a$-$a$: cycles are also required to be *non-empty*, so $a$-$a$ doesn't count as a cycle (unless there's a "loop" on that node). ... You should include that example in the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

**Path:** A string of alternating vertices and edges $v_1e_1v_2e_2\dots v_{n-1}e_{n-1}v_n$, ($n\geq 2$) is said to be a path if no vertex repeat.

**Circular path:** A string of alternating vertices edges $v_1e_1v_2e_2\dots v_{n-1}e_{n-1}v_n$, ($n\geq 2$) is said to be a circular path if no vertex repeat exept for $v_1=v_n$ and no edge repeat.

Now if the graph has parallel edges $e_1$ and $e_2$ joining two vertex $u$ and $v$. Then $ue_1ve_2u$ is a circular path of size $2$. But for simple graph since there is no parallel edge so there is no circular path of size $2$. Because in this case edges will repeat.

Now most of the books concern only simple graphs, so they do not include the "no edge repeat" part. But for a non simple graph it is required to mention that. Otherwise for $n=2$ an ambiguity occurs what you have mentioned.

In your question you have not said the graph is simple or not. But since you have not mention edge, so $ab$ and $ba$ are same edges. So here the edge is repeating, so $aba$ is not a circular path.